# Copy Physics To Multiple Objects

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Using the cell fracture addon, I created many objects from my mesh. I want to have a rigid body physics on all of them. How would I copy one of the fractured pieces physics to all the pieces? I tired ctrl L and the copy attributes addon, but none of them have the option. Any help is great.

Comment: do any of the objects have physics properties? Or are all of them plain meshes that need them? Or do you have an object with physics properties that you wish everyone had as well?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you have one object that has physics properties and you wish that the other object had the same properties:

1. Select all object that you wish to copy the physics properties to
2. Select the object you wish to copy the physics properties from

   - note: We select this one last so that It becomes the active selected object. This is the object that has the desired physics properties.
3. Then In the Physics panel under Object Tools choose Copy From Active.

[image]

---

If none of them have physics properties than you will want to add them:

1. Select all objects that need physics properties.
2. Physics -> Add Active

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find the rigid body tools. Could you post a screenshot of your whole desktop?

Comment: one sec. I will. What version of blender are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.69

Comment: @user2593789 The tabs will be introduced in 2.7, but you find all the items in the left panel.

Comment: Thanks, that works to copy the settings. It doesn't work if I want to actually add a rigid body physics to multiple objects. any way to do that?

Comment: select them all: Add Active, I will update answer

Answer (score 16):

If you only want to copy single properties, you can right click on the property which you want to copy and select *Copy To Selected*:

[image]

This will copy the value of that setting from the *[active object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Selections_and_the_Active_Object)* (the object with the yellow outline, usually the last selected) to any *[selected objects](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Selections_and_the_Active_Object)* (objects with an orange outline).

Note that this works for non-physics settings too.

Comment: This is really a useful and potentially more powerful feature than the chosen answer.  Up-vote for usefulness.

Answer (score 11):

For 2.8# series you can copy items from either the search menu `Copy Rigid Body Settings`

[image]

or from the 3D View Menu *Object > Rigid Body > Copy From Active*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also just select all your objects, then on the last one you select, add the physics property you want them all to have, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select *modifiers*.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.81a on Windows, I had to add all objects I wanted to simulate into a collection, set physics on one object, then <kbd>RMB</kbd> the collection, choose "select objects" and then in 3d window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select *Collection*. It works!

*Edit* I was NOT using Cell Fracture add-on. I was using many blocks via *Mesh>Extras>Wall Factory* from the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* add-on.

I just tested this method with Cell Fracture add-on and the same method works; you still have to add to a collection and link collection in order to distribute physics data of an object to the rest of the objects in that collection. [image: Wall Factory from Add Mesh: Extra Objects add-on]

You can also link modifiers like Bevel for a nicer look for your bricks.
[image: Linked Bevel modifier]

Separate test with Cell Fracture add-on. Had to add Suzanne's parts to a separate collection, set physics of one object, select all objects in collection, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to  link to collection and then physics were applied!
[image: Cell fracture test]