# Enable Collision for multiple objects

Tags: objects, physics

Please note that the answers to other questions have not applied to this problem.

I have a large number of shards created in the Fracture Modifier that I've converted to Objects.  I want all of these objects to have Collision enabled.  There are too many to do one by one.

I've tried the suggestions in this forum.  None work.

1. Use Copy from Active (no go)
2. Ctrl-L (no go)

I've tried applying Collision before I apply the Fracture Modifier.  The resultant shards/objects do not maintain Collision.

I've tried the same procedure used to change the scale of multiple object (Select them all, Alt-Click on the x, y and z Scale settings).  It does not work for Collisions.

Thanks Duarte but your solution does not apply to Collisions.

Thx for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Physics To Multiple Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7411/copy-physics-to-multiple-objects)

Comment: Previous suggestions do not work.

Comment: The suggestion reference by Duarte only works for Rigid Object.  It doesn't work for Collisions.  Test it with a simple 3 cube group and selecting the multiple objects with Select Border.  I can't get it to work.  Thanks though Duarte.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick python script to add the collision modifier for all selected objects. Just select all the objects to be made into collision objects and run the script, script is not at all optimized as it is using `bpy.ops`, so anything above 300 objects might take 1 or 2 secs to apply.

```
import bpy
for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = i
     bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='COLLISION')
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all other objects that you want the same physics applied to and join them as a single object. Apply collision physics. Then go into edit mode and select them all and separate by loose parts. Depending on how many objects it might take a while or freeze but it's a work-around.