# Copy Physics to multiple objects in Blender 2.8

Tags: physics

I'm trying to convert a number of objects to have 'Rigid Body' Physics at the same time rather than having to do it one by one.

[image]

I know in 2.79 you could use the left hand toolbar to select "add active" as seen in this thread: [Copy Physics To Multiple Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7411/copy-physics-to-multiple-objects)

But I can't seem to find that option in 2.8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select your objects to copy to and then the object to copy from.

Then search <kbd>F3</kbd> and enter the search string as "Copy Rigid Body Settings"

[image: search for copy]

Or from the **Object** menu **Rigid Body->Copy From Active**

[image: menu of rigid bodies]

You can also *right click* this menu and **Assign Shortcut** to assign the action a key press of your choice.